# Add custom functionalities to Doxygen

Tags: documentation, doxygen

I'm working on my project which uses Doxygen, and I need to implement a custom Google search bar and a drop-down of versions like what OpenCV has on their documentation page [here](https://docs.opencv.org/master/).

[image]

I searched through the code on their Github [repo](https://github.com/opencv/opencv), but I couldn't find a place where those are implemented.

Doxygen's documentation [page](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/index.html) doesn't have anything on this either, and I couldn't find an answer anywhere else.

Does anyone have an idea on how to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Not sure what the exact question is, an image might be a good idea to clarify. At first glance it looks a bit like that you want to have a custom html header.

Comment: @albert just added a picture for clarity. So I did look at how to make a custom html header file, but it looks like OpenCV just has a default one (https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/doc/header.html)

Comment: This looks exactly like I intended the custom header.html (default version can be obtained by means of `doxygen  -w html headerFile footerFile styleSheetFile [configFile]`). Probably the do some processing on it to get the google bar instead of the comment they placed in it, just check the resulting html code of the opencv project and their build procedure.